Movement of fluid in a container upon impact
I am a boxer and have been thinking about neck muscles. Do they make you have less Parkinson?
Consider an infinitely stiff and hard container that can't be moved. The container is filled with fluid. We can assume that the fluid is similar to water for our purposes. There is a small sphere inside the container. If a blow is inflicted upon the container, is it possible for the particles inside, and therefore the sphere, to move? Will the external force send a wave of compression into the fluid?

You can probably test this easily enough at home with a cup and something that floats in water.

"Do they make you have less Parkinson?" What does it mean to have "less Parkinson?" I don't understand.

@KyleKanos I'm sorry but I do not possess a theoretical immovable container. I'm interested in a mathematically derived argumentation not 6th grade experiments

If the container is "infinitely hard and stiff", then the container is effectively a rigid body. There can be no sound waves inside the container material as any disturbance propagates instantly to the entire container. Since the container can't be moved, nothing happens.
In reality, the stiffness is not infinite and the blow will cause a compressive wave that travels through the container. Some of it will indeed be transmitted to the liquid at the interface.

Great, that's what I thought that the container has to change form in order to move the liquid inside. I am interested in how would the deformation wave travel inside in the liquid and the force affecting the floating body.could you point me to some laws/theorems that would help estimate the force affecting the floating body with relation to the stiffness of the container?  I'm interested in finding out whether the neck muscles can hold the brain in place when taking a hit

@MaciejFilipiak For the transmission of waves, there is a standard law involving reflection and transmission coefficients, which depend on the speed of sound in the materials. As for the floating body, you will have to determine the water waves generated, which is nontrivial.
